# Actions on Google dialogflow api v2 library gets location undefined

Tags: firebase, location, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've been building an AoG action for a while. I'm stuck with location problem. I'm asking for permissions for location and name as in the code below.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { dialogflow, Permission, Confirmation } = require('actions-on-google');


const app = dialogflow({clientId:CLIENT_ID);
  app.intent('ask.for.permission', (conv) => {
  const options = 
  {
    context: 'To address you by name and know your location',
    permissions: ['NAME', 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION'],
  };
  conv.ask(new Permission(options));
});

app.intent('ask.for.permission.confirmation', (conv, params, confirmationGranted) => {
  const {name} = conv.user;
  const {loc} = conv.device.location;
  console.log(name);
  console.log(loc);
  if (confirmationGranted) {
    if (name) {
      conv.ask(`I'll send your orders ${name.display}.`);
    }
  }
});
```

Yet, whenever I run this, even I try to show them in logs, it says 'undefined'. I can get user's name but location is still undefined. I thought it is because I'm using dialogflow library, but I don't know how to find a solution. I'm open for advice to get location other than using actionssdk, or can I use both of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because it returns the location as a LatLng object. Try conv.device.location.coordinates.latitude / conv.device.location.coordinates.longitude